# show list-items in div without using negative margins

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn css.

I have some html as follows:

```
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <span id="websiteName">
            VISHAL
        </span>

        <div id="languageBar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hindi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Marathi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gujarati</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

I have written some css as follows:

```
* 
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#header 
{
    background: #353535;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #808080;
}

    div#header > span#websiteName
    {
        font-family: TEMPUS SANS ITC;
        font-size: 44px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #0094ff;
        margin-left:18%;
    }

ul.nav
{
    list-style:none;
}
    ul.nav li 
    {
        width:100px;
        float:right;
        display:inline;
    }

        ul.nav li a
        {
            display:block;
            width:100px;
            /*height:31px;*/ 
            float:left;
            /*margin-top:150px;*/
            /*text-decoration:none;*/
            /*color:black;*/
        }
```

My output:

You can see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/4eumnk2g/4/) to have a look at my output.

I want to have some changes in output like:

the list-items shown are below the black box. I want them to be inside that black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eumnk2g/10/)

set padding instead of margin and use `float: left`

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS `position` property you can achieve it.

```
 div#header 
{
background: #353535;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #808080;
position:relative;
}

ul.nav
{
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
top:28px;
right:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4eumnk2g/6/)

Comment: Thanks. This answer also works but not as good as @ManProgrammer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your menu floats outside `#header`. The solution is to let `#header` know that there are floated items inside it.

You can make that happen by adding `overflow: auto;` to it.

```
div#header {
    background: #353535;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #808080;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4eumnk2g/9/).

Comment: Thanks. This answer also works but not as good as @ManProgrammer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ways to move the links up:

with negative margins:

```
#languageBar {
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

or with relative positioning:

```
#languageBar {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}
```

or since you are floating the title to the left, you can float the links to the right:

```
#languageBar {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply float the `#languageBar` div to the right

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4eumnk2g/15/)

```
#languageBar {
    float: right;
}
```